# Android Bluetooth Quick Device Discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy application to scan surrounding advertise-only device quickly (10 times or more per second) and get their address with RSSI.
According to [Android Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery%28%29), the discovery is asynchronous and takes around 12 seconds. Is there any way to set this time? Or is it possible to directly communicate with the device using HCI or the Bluetooth stack?

Comment: Doing quick scans 10 times a second would not be useful because you have low probability of hearing anything from other devices, and your burst scans may become always out of phase from when other device is transmitting advertisement.  You want to scan continuously for a long enough time that you are going to hear an adv from most/all devices in range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about Bluetooth classic API and not low energy API. It is that slow because classic bluetooth stack doesn't have fast advertising intervals and there would be no use for such fast scaning times.

Since Bluetooth low energy is not officially included in Android SDK there is not way to set the time or to scan Bluetooth LE devices. You can try to use Boardcom BLE API but from what I can tell it is in alpha stages and for now only few mobile phones can use it.